# Saving a Image View having another masked ImageView on it?

Tags: ios, swift

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr4nd.png)**My View hierarchy is**

**ContentView containing 
Background ImageView
and a Front ImageView**

What i am trying to do is as soon as my view gets Load i.e viewDidLoad() is called i am applying a masking on the front ImageView. Like this:

```
func viewDidLoad() {

  maskLayer.frame = frontImageView.bounds
        maskLayer.shadowRadius = 5
        maskLayer.shadowPath = CGPath(roundedRect: frontImageView.bounds.insetBy(dx: CGFloat(5), dy: CGFloat(5)), cornerWidth: 10, cornerHeight: 10, transform: nil)
        maskLayer.shadowOpacity = 15
        maskLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        maskLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        frontImageView.layer.mask = maskLayer 

}
```

and then what i want is to save the image that i got and i am doing it like this:

I am calling this method to get the image:

```
 func returnFinalImage() -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backGroundImageView.frame.size, backGroundImageView.isOpaque, 0.0)
        contentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return finalImage!
    }
```

But when the image is saved to the Photos lib, what i get is a Blank Canvas with no image there.

I hope i am able to convey my self.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. Following is the code:

```
func returnFinalImage() -> UIImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: CGFloat(contentView.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(contentView.frame.size.height)))
    view.drawHierarchy(in: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(view.frame.size.width), height: CGFloat(view.frame.size.height)), afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let image: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image!
}
```

Comment: what is "view" in this code? contentView or one of the imageViews (Background or front) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering from contentView's layer while there is no mention of contentView anywhere else in your code.

I would recommend replacing

```
contentView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

with

```
frontImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
```

Comment: ContentView is the View on which Both of my ImageView are Placed i.e background Image view and front Image View , Where my background ImageView is of same size as that of the content View.

Comment: I have Attached the Screen Shot as well of the Hierarchy.Please have a look to it.

Comment: Think of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` as creating a blank canvas. Then by using `layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)`you are asking to draw the layer on to the canvas. In your case, contentView's layer was never assigned anything. So when you render conteView.layer, you get a blank canvas. See if changing it to the frontImageView helps.

Comment: Also, you might want to set the `opaque` property to `false` and change it to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backGroundImageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)`

Comment: Thank you for the Reply , ill update you soon with the result.

Comment: Hi, See I have designed my UI using interface Builder. Where my both image View are on Content View. What i am doing here is i have masked the front image view as i have wrote the code in viewDidLoad() , if I am not masking the front Image View and i try to save, the code works perfectly fine. But when masking is done only the saved image is the Background Image View but not with the front Image View on it.